# Autohotkey adding control modifier onto remapped right alt key

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to remap my right alt key to the letter s.

RAlt::s

I put that into a ahk file and ran it, when I tested it in my browser the save as window popped up as if I pressed ctrl s. I tried it with the letter b and again the bookmarks sidebar popped up as if I pressed ctrl b. I am following the instructions as presented in here, https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm, and it has worked for me before. The only thing different is that this is on a fresh install of the latest windows 10.

Comment: Try [running the script as administrator](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs).

Comment: I tried that already, didn't work unfortunatley

Answer (score 0):

I did test it out `RAlt::s` on my Windows System, with a fresh (latest) Windows 10 64bit and the latest Autohotkey (64bit unicode) - and it works on my Windows System.

1 Maybe your keyboard layout is not setup on the right languages try to test RCtrl::s

2 or the fresh windows 10 install/Update/Upgrade was not right completed.

3 or try this code

```
RAlt::
send s
return
```